# Sign up counter - PHP?

Tags: php, counter

I am looking to find out how http://getfixedapp.com/ was able to show the amount of users that signed up above the sign up link. I used Developer Tools to try to see what they used. Any help?

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. The current question is too broad.

Comment: I would imagine a simple ``echo mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select count(`id`) from `users`"))[0];`` would do it.

Comment: @Kolink , You mention `mysql_` just for the concept , right ?

Comment: Create a integer field somewhere and for every successful sign up, add one to its value!

Comment: @OfirBaruch Does it matter? A prepared statement would be majorly overkill for a static query like that. In any case, I'd use a slightly more complex solution that involved Memcache to avoid recounting for every single request.

Comment: @Kolink Good point but using `mysql` and `pdo` or `mysqli` would be a mess. But as said , good point indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Would be very easy with php.

On the backend, they increment a variable each time someone signs up, and they probably store this variable inside a database.

You will not be able to see this using Developer Tools : php is executed on the server side and invisible on the front end.

Comment: Why not simply count the number of rows?